# How can I avoid labels overlapping?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to create a network containing nodes with long labels, but this results in the labels overlapping with each other, making it difficult to read them all clearly.

How can I separate those labels?

How can I align elements in one compound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Adjust the relative sizes of your labels in your stylesheet
- Adjust your layout so that your nodes are spread farther apart
- Use short labels; you can show long text elsewhere, like in a tooltip

Comment: Thank you so much maxkfranz! There is another question I didn't figure out. Is it possible to align nodes? or can I put a table inside of a node to make them aligned?

Comment: You can position nodes manually, or you can position them via a layout.  It's up to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `avoidOverlap: true` and `nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: true`.

```
var layout = cy.elements().layout({
    name: 'dagre',
    avoidOverlap: true,
    nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: true
});
layout.run();
```

Here I am using the [cytoscape-dagre](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre), but the same is possible with the layouts that come with cytoscape.js according to the [documentation](https://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/grid), for example with the grid layout.

Interestingly these options are not listed in the documentation of cytoscape-dagre, but they do work with it.